# How to log a distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, logarithms, cumulative-distribution-functions

My understanding: Equation $(5)$ can be obtained when we let $e^x=\left({e^t}/{\theta}\right)^{\beta}$, which $x=\beta\,(t-\log\theta)$ , and substitute into $(4)$.

My question: Why equation $(7)$ is $\beta\,\left(Y-\log\theta\right)$ instead of $\beta\,(T-\log\theta)$ ? These lead to me not understanding the equation $(8)$ as well.

We know that the CDF of a complete Weibull Distribution as below :

\begin{equation}\text{Prob}\,(T<t)=1-e^{-\left({t}/{\theta}\right)^{\beta}}\tag{1}\label{eq:1}\end{equation}

The random variable $Y=\log T$ is called a log-Weibull variable. We have :
\begin{align}
\text{Prob}\,(Y < t)
& = \text{Prob}\,(\log T < t) \tag{2}\label{eq: 2}\\
& = \text{Prob}\,(T < e^t)\tag{3}\label{eq: 3} \\
& = 1-e^{-\left({e^t}/{\theta}\right)^{\beta}} \tag{4}\label{eq: 4} \\ 
& = 1-e^{-e^{\beta(t-\log\,\theta)}} \tag{5}\label{eq: 5}\\
\end{align}

The random variable $X=\beta\,(Y-\log\,\theta)$ is called as a reduced log-Weibull variable. The distribution function $X$ is

\begin{align}
F(x)
& = \text{Prob}\,(X<x) \tag{6}\label{eq: 6}\\
& = \text{Prob}\,(\beta\,(Y-\log\,\theta)<x) \tag{7}\label{eq: 7} \\
& = 1-e^{-e^x} , \,\,\,-\infty<x<\infty\tag{8}\label{eq: 8} \\ 
\end{align}

Reference : https://www.jstor.org/stable/1267267

Comment: You just expand $X=\beta(Y-\log\theta)$ in $\Pr(X<x)$, right?

Comment: Hi @dvdgrgrtt, I think the book didn't expand it, it just substitute it instead...

Comment: Yes, for me "expand" and "substitute" are synonyms in this case, sorry for the confusion. But I don't get your question - (7) comes from (6) and the definition of $X$, why do you want to put a $T$ there?

Comment: The "expand" and "substitute" apply in equation (7), right? 

Because from equation 5, I can see that the book let $e^x=(e^t/\theta)^\beta$, which don't have variable $Y$, but in equation $(7)$ the variable $Y$ appeared, I am confused...

Comment: Can I double confirm with you that, how to get equation (5) from equation (4)? Suddenly, I doubt my understanding...

Comment: From (4) to (5): $\theta=e^{\log \theta} \implies e^t/\theta=e^{t-\log\theta}$. But that's it, then they define a new random variable $X$, which has nothing to do with the $x$ you wrote to justify (5). Finally, we can add an intermediate step after (7): $F(x)=\Pr(Y<x/\beta + \log\theta)$ and you only have to use (5) with $t=x/\beta + \log\theta$. (I'm assuming $\beta>0$, otherwise it won't work.)

Comment: Hey @dvdgrgrtt, finally I understood the front part! Thank you! For the part behind, I have used pen and pencil to write it out. Still digesting.. will update you once I got it, thankyou!

Comment: Hi @dvdgrgrtt, sorry,

in (6), $F(x)=\text{Pr}(X<x)=\text{Pr}(\beta(Y-\text{log}\,\theta))=\text{P}(Y<x/\beta+\text{log}\,\theta)$, assume $t=x/\beta+\text{log}\,\theta$, so, $F(x)=\text{P}(Y<t)$, still back to the same places which is equation (2) to (5) isn't? Can't reach equation (8)... thank you for your patience...

Comment: (5) says $\Pr(Y<t) = 1-\exp(-\exp(\beta(t-\log\theta)))$ (where $\exp(u)=e^u$) and "improved" (7) says $F(x)=\Pr(Y<x/\beta+\log\theta)$. So, to compute $F(x)$, you can use (5) with $t=x/\beta+\log\theta$: $F(x)=1-\exp(-\exp(\beta(x/\beta+\log\theta-\log\theta)))=1-\exp(-\exp(\beta(x/\beta)))=1-\exp(-\exp(x))$. I hope it's clear now, because I'm not sure I can come up with another version. And we should stop or move to a chat, we can't keep commenting here.

Comment: @dvdgrgrtt I am truly appreciated on your patience in explaining to me. Thank you sincerely. Noteed, how can we move to chat anyways?

Comment: Discussion moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149730/discussion-between-dvdgrgrtt-and-gambit)